# Issue with the Timeline Settings in Health Cloud

Tags: health-cloud

[image]

When I am trying to create a new Person Account I am  getting an error of "Can't Find valid Timeline Settings." I tried to create a new Timeline Configuration with the task Object and I also created a new Document in the Documents Tab.

Answer (score 0):

This warning message shows up when you don't define any Timeline Configuration records in your Org.

Solution:

Go to App Launcher and Search for Timeline view configurations and Select.
Click on New Timeline Configuration and use this link to understand the limitations involved- [Timeline Customize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_config_timeline.htm)

Note: Make sure you have proper permissions to the Timeline Object.
Good news is For System Admin you have no issues all permissions are given by healthcloud.

Hope this helps!